# How can I use rollup to process a JS file in a non-strict mode?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollup, rollupjs

Today, when I used rollup to process several js files, an error occurred. After checking, the reason was that the js file to be processed contained a syntax that was not allowed in strict mode, which caused the babel to report an error. Later, during the test, I deleted the babel and just used rollup, but it still reported an error. Test file does not indicate 'use strict'.

So, how can I use rollup to process a JS file in a non-strict mode?

The js file to be processed by rollup:

```
var public = 1;
console.log(public);
```

The rollup file:

```
const rollup = require('rollup');
let iOptions = {
    input: "strict.js",
    plugins: [
    ]
}

const oOptions = {
    format: 'cjs',
    strict: false,
    dir: './',
    file: 'out.js',
    sourcemap: false
}

async function build() {
    const bundle = await rollup.rollup(iOptions);
    await bundle.write(oOptions);
}

build();
```

With babel, the error is: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: D:\EC-IoT\Bugs\SyntaxError\strict.js: public is a reserved word in strict mode (1:4)`

Only rollup, the error is : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The keyword 'public' is reserved`

Comment: I think what you mean is to let me try to avoid this, but the current demand is that the rollup can handle such files, including but not limited to using `with`, `delete`, `arguments`, etc.

Comment: as it mentions `public` is reserved keyword with or without strict mode on, hope this is clear

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when I run this code with nodejs, it works fine. So, what puzzles me is, why does the rollup report an error when processing it? Is it because rollup defaults to strict mode when parsing files like this?

Comment: no it has nothing to do with strict mode, it simply refuses to use reserved keywords as variable names

Comment: So, is this the situation caused by the rollup? Including using arguments as function variables, using the with keyword, and delete a variable using delete.

Comment: maybe it is a setting in rollup but still has nothing to do with strict-mode

Comment: Um... I understand what you mean. The reason I use this way is that the place where the error is made is not allowed by the strict mode. Maybe I should go to the rollup project and submit an issue. Thank you very much.